# Hiding a sub category in AngularJS with filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of content, it has two levels.  My data is sorted so I just iterate over it to show it.  So I have this

```
Category 1
  Subcategory1
     Item1
     Item2
  Subcategory2
     Item3
     Item4
  Subcategory3
     Item5
     Item6
  Subcategory4
     Item7
     Item8
Category 2
  Subcategory1
     Item9
     Item10
  Subcategory2
     Item11
     Item12
```

and so on.  I also have a text filter, so you can enter text and my content list filters based on both titles and tags.  This all works fine.  What I want to do, is hide Subcategory 1 in Category 2, if Item9 and Item10 are excluded by the filter.  I have 2500 items and it's already a bit slow.  Instead of counting the items again, I want to count them as they are filtered.  Which means when the filter starts, I need to reset my list and then count as items are found.  I have two controllers, the parent has the text box in it, and the child is used for each item, because I've read that is faster than using a filter ( because the filter removes things from the DOM ).  I'm still not sure if it's true, I am experimenting.  In the meantime, this is in the parent controller:

```
$scope.doFilter = function()
{
    for (var c = 0; c < $scope.categories.length; ++c)
    {
        var categoryId = $scope.categories[c].Id;


        for (var r = 0; r < $scope.regions.length; ++r)
        {
            var regionId = $scope.regions[r].Id;
            $scope.showRegions[String(categoryId) + String(regionId)] = 0;
        }
    }


    $scope.$broadcast("triggerFilters", {});
}
```

and then this is at the bottom of my search method in the child controller:

```
    if (!excluded)
    {
        var key = String($scope.item.CategoryId) + String($scope.region.Id);

        if ($scope.$parent.showRegions[key] == null)
            $scope.$parent.showRegions[key] = 0;

        $scope.$parent.showRegions[key]++;
    }
```

Remember, there's an instance of this child controller, for each element, it's like this ( this is a cut down version, for readability ):

```
<div data-ng-repeat="category in fullList">
        <a>{{category.Name}}</a>
        <div >
            <div data-ng-repeat="region in regions | orderBy: 'Name'">
                {{region.Name}}
                <div >
                    <ul>
                        <li  ng-controller="filterController" ng-hide="isExcludedByFilter"
                            data-ng-repeat="item in category.regions[region.Name].items | orderBy: 'Name'">
                            {{item.Name}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, when I set breakpoints in Chrome, I can see my collection of item counts growing.  But the Angular inspector in Chrome freezes ( perhaps because I have 2500 controllers ? ) and if I set a break point on the method called when I push 'search', the collections are all empty again.  So, I've attempted to add filters, but the lists never show if I add an ng-hide, because the collection is always empty, although it fills up as the search occurs.

I am using $parent, because each item has it's own controller and I thought if you modify a parent item, you get a local copy.  So, this is visibly working, but the values are disappearing when the search ends, and I don't know why.

Thanks for looking

Comment: What if I was to create a service that holds this data, and inject it in to both controllers, will that help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I sorted this out.  Angular maintains variables at the level of each scope, so a child scope inherits a value, but if you change it in the child level, the parent one is unchanged unless you use $scope.$parent.  My project has evolved, as I've learned more about Angular.  I didn't quite realise I had two nested scopes at the point of my data items.  So, I needed to change $scope.$parent, to $scope.$parent.$parent, and all was well.  Now I just need to work out why it's so slow.....